# How to setup/fill a vector of structures c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a struct and some elements in it, I am trying to create a vector of structs and fill it up but tbh im pulling my hair out cause I have no idea what I am doing. Could someone please help me with how I should set this up?

'''

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//define structs
struct animalS
{
    string animalType = "none";
    int animalCount = 0;
    bool animalEndangered = false;
};

int main()
{
    vector<animalS> animal;

    animal.push_back("" , 0 , true);
    
}
```

'''

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLvGt.png)

Comment: use `push_back` like this: `animal.push_back({"", 0, true})`, which is a short form of `animal.push_back(animalS{"", 0, true})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two mistakes, first one your `animalS` struct doesn't have a constructor, you should add constructor like this:

```
animalS(const std::string &animalType, int animalCount, bool animalEndangered)
  : animalType(animalType)
  , animalCount(animalCount)
  , animalEndangered(animalEndangered)
  {}
```

And use `push_back()` like this:
`animal.push_back(animalS("" , 0 , true))`

Comment: This is an ideal use-case for `animal.emplace_back("", 0, true)`, which will directly construct inside the vector instead of creating a temporary struct and copying it in like `push_back({"", 0, true})`

Comment: `you should add constructor` is a bad recommendation. One of `animal.push_back(animalS{"", 0, true})` or `animal.emplace_back("", 0, true)`  w/o adding a constructor is better.

Comment: How would i then print out lets say the string animalType?